# ActiveRecord looking for user ID=1 after db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I reset my DB and am getting this error on every page:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in HomeController#index

Couldn't find User with id=1

lib/authenticated_system.rb:15:in `current_user'
lib/authenticated_system.rb:23:in `logged_in?'
lib/authenticated_system.rb:36:in `login_required'
```

The offending code in `authenticated_system.rb` is:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id].present?
end
```

So I'm unsure why it's looking fo the User with id=1. There are no users. `current_user` shouldn't return anything. Why am I getting this error?

For reference, `logged_in?` is:

```
def logged_in?
 !current_user.nil?
end
```

And `login_required`:

```
def login_required
  logged_in? && authorized? ? true : access_denied
end
```

Comment: you probably still have a session running. and in that session is a `user_id = 1` stored ;) Clear your session and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you closed your browser and restarted it?

Sessions exist for however long your browser is open. Just because you reset your db doesn't mean the session is gone.

Answer (score 0):

User.find will raise the exception ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if it can't find the record. You probably want to use User.find_by_id which will return nil if it can't find anything. This way if the session references a user_id that doesn't exist (as in this case when you reset the db, but the session cookie still present - also would happen if a user was deleted), you get the desired result.